# height 100% en plantilla CSS excesivamene básica con DOS errores

Tags: css, height

pretendo tener una plantilla HTML muy básica con CUATRO cajones:

1// Cajón VERDE "cuerpo/body/conenedor de TODO"

2// Cajón ROSA "menú principal/header"

3// Cajón GRIS menú de la izquierda enláces den LETRAS

4// Cajón AMARILLO contenido de cáda página

he pensado que en el interior del cajón AMARILLO puedo colocar n cajones
con contenidos de imagenes, video, etc...

ésta es la plantilla HTML y sí, debe ser x-HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" /><style type="text/css">@import url("https://yahoo.com/css.css");</style><script type="text/javascript" src="https://yahoo.com/java.js"></script><link rel="icon" href="https://yahoo.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><title>Hola! {yahoo}</title></head><body>

<div id="todito">
<nav><a href="">LINK 1</a><a href="">LINK 2</a><a href="">LINK 3</a><a href="">LINK 4</a></nav>

<div id="contenido"<h3>CONTENIDO de cáda una de las páginas :-)</h3><p>uu</p><p>uu</p></div>

<div id="menu"><p><a href="">LINK A</a></p><p><a href="">LINK B</a></p><p><a href="">LINK C</a></p><p><a href="">LINK D</a></p><p><a href="">LINK E</a></p><p><a href="">LINK F</a></p><p><a href="">LINK G</a></p><p><a href="">LINK H</a></p><p><a href="">LINK I</a></p></div>

<div id="pie">0.01294 segundos - <a href="mailto:r@yahoo.com">© r@yahoo.com</a><em id="lenguaje"></em></div>

</div>

</body></html>
```

y éste es el CSS:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
html,body{height:100%;font-family:verdana;font-size:0.90em;}
nav{margin:auto;text-align:center;background:lightpink;color:green;border-bottom:1px solid black;}
nav a{border-bottom:1px solid transparent;border-top:1px solid transparent;display:block;padding:1em;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;}
nav a:hover{border-top:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;background:gold;}
nav a.bb0:hover{border-bottom:1px solid transparent;}
nav a.bt0:hover{border-top:1px solid transparent;}

#cosmos{background:yellowgreen;color:black;min-height:100%;}
#menu{transition:1s;width:100%;background:gainsboro;color:black;text-align:center;}
#contenido{padding-top:2em;background:gold;color:black;padding-bottom:3em;}
#pie{bottom:0;background:#010105;color:#fdfffe;font-family:verdana;font-size:0.67em;position:fixed;text-align:center;width:100%;}
#pie a:active, #pie a:link, #pie a:visited{background:#010105;color:#fdfffe;text-decoration:none;}

@media(min-width:600px){

nav{padding:1em;}
nav a{display:inline-block;padding:1em;border:1px solid transparent;}
nav a:hover,nav a.bb0:hover,nav a.bt0:hover{border:1px solid black;}

#contenido{
width:calc(100% - (20em + 5em + 5em));
margin-right:5em;
float:right;
padding-left:3em;
}
#menu{
width:20em;margin-left:5em;border-right:1px solid #000;
}
#contenido,#menu{min-height:100%;}
}
```

pretendo que el menú de la IZQUIERDA (caja GRIS) se despliegue vertical completo,
por ello utilizo `min-height:100%;` pero no me funciona.

También pretendo que el cajón amarillo se despliegue en TODO su vertical, por ello utilizo `min-height:100%;`
y tampóco m funciona.

con ello,
tengo DOS preguntas:

1// debo utilizar MÁS cajones "contenedores" para lograr el vertical al 100% ?

2// de dónde puedo obtener plantillas MUY básicas que solo tengan el modelo de las CAJAS sin contenido ni JavaScript, por ejemplo en https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_templates.asp hay buenas plantillas pero ya tienen imagenes y texto, hay plantillas de CAJONES CSS?

gracias!

ah!,
los DOS errres son:

1// el cajón GRIS no se despliega 100% vetical

2// el cajón AMARILLO no se despliega 100% vetical

Comment: No es una solución, pero tienes un error en tu código HTML. A `<div id="contenido"<h3>CONTENIDO de cáda una` le falta el cierre `>` del elemento `#contenido`.

Comment: Puedes añadir el estilo `height: 100vh;` al contenido gris (esto toma el alto de la pantalla). Si el alto de la cabecera va a ser siempre fijo se podría mejorar con `height: calc(100vh - {ALTO_CABECERA}px);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edito...

Bien, pues prueba esta edición, solamente agrupa el contenido en un contenedor padre, y usa el `height: 100%;` en ambos contenedores.

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
html,body{height:100%;font-family:verdana;font-size:0.90em;}
nav{text-align:center;background:lightpink;color:green;border-bottom:1px solid black;}
nav a{border-bottom:1px solid transparent;border-top:1px solid transparent;display:block;padding:1em;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;}
nav a:hover{border-top:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;background:gold;}
nav a.bb0:hover{border-bottom:1px solid transparent;}
nav a.bt0:hover{border-top:1px solid transparent;}

#todito {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#cosmos{background:yellowgreen;color:black;min-height:100%;}
#menu{transition:1s;width:100%;background:gainsboro;color:black;text-align:center;}
#contenido{padding-top:2em;background:gold;color:black;padding-bottom:3em;}
#pie{bottom:0;background:#010105;color:#fdfffe;font-family:verdana;font-size:0.67em;position:fixed;text-align:center;width:100%;}
#pie a:active, #pie a:link, #pie a:visited{background:#010105;color:#fdfffe;text-decoration:none;}

@media(min-width:600px){

nav{padding:1em;}
nav a{display:inline-block;padding:1em;border:1px solid transparent;}
nav a:hover,nav a.bb0:hover,nav a.bt0:hover{border:1px solid black;}

#contenido{
width:calc(100% - (20em + 5em + 5em));
margin-right:5em;
float:right;
padding-left:3em;
}
#menu{
width:20em;margin-left:5em;border-right:1px solid #000;
}
#contenido,#menu{min-height:100%;}
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" /><style type="text/css">@import url("https://yahoo.com/css.css");</style><script type="text/javascript" src="https://yahoo.com/java.js"></script><link rel="icon" href="https://yahoo.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><title>Hola! {yahoo}</title></head><body>

<div id="todito">
<nav><a href="">LINK 1</a><a href="">LINK 2</a><a href="">LINK 3</a><a href="">LINK 4</a></nav>

<div class="container">
<div id="contenido"><h3>CONTENIDO de cáda una de las páginas :-)</h3><p>uu</p><p>uu</p></div>

<div id="menu"><p><a href="">LINK A</a></p><p><a href="">LINK B</a></p><p><a href="">LINK C</a></p><p><a href="">LINK D</a></p><p><a href="">LINK E</a></p><p><a href="">LINK F</a></p><p><a href="">LINK G</a></p><p><a href="">LINK H</a></p><p><a href="">LINK I</a></p></div>
</div>
<div id="pie">0.01294 segundos - <a href="mailto:r@yahoo.com">© r@yahoo.com</a><em id="lenguaje"></em></div>

</div>

</body></html>
```

Una sálida mas elaborada sería el uso de flexbox, te recomiendo te documentes sobre el mismo, las cajas flotantes `float` ya casi están en desuso.

Comment: Gracias @Gabri, he colocado ésta .línea en el CSS: `#todito{background:yellowgreen;color:black;min-height:100vh;}` y nada cambia; el error de NO CERRAR el DIV (`<div id="contenido"<h3>`) fué PEGANDO el código aquí. @Elboy también coloqué tu instrucción y no funcionó. Gracias.

Comment: Prueba con la edición que hice a la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elboy, míra cómo se vé cuando PEGO el código que me haz brindado: http://unir.team/4cajas en efecto, solo quiero 4 cajas y no sé por que se vuelve un lío ... (me refiero a que exíste un SCROLL cuando no debería existir)

Comment: En tu ejemplo no has incluido el contenedor .container como te lo puse en el ejemplo, si quieres que no haya scroll entonces en vez de usar height: 100% usa min-height: calc(100vh - 71px); 71px el es alto de tu nav. Lógicamente si el contenido de la página supera el alto del viewport, siempre verás el scroll.

Comment: gracias @Elboy lo que sucede es que el HEADER es dinámico, puede CAMBIAR de altura y el tamaño del texto también. En algunas paginas habrá MUCHAS lineas y en otras POCAS, por ello el SCROLL debe existir solo al ser necesario

Comment: Entonces lo ideal es usar css flex  en tu contenedor #todito, he realizado modificación, mira como se observa en la respuesta. De esta forma el scroll solo se verá si el contenido crece.

Comment: Gracias @Elboy, cuánto me cobras por hacerme la PLANTILLA? de solo 5 CAJAS, te pago con PAYPAL, te parece bien US $5 ? seria: HEADeR + MENU + CONTENIDO + FOOTHER, yo solo tengo HEADER y FOOTHER. En que pais estas?

Comment: Gracias @Elboy, tu plantilla trabaja MUY BIEN: http://unir.team/Elboy ahora bien, por favor díme: es IMPOSIBLE lograr ése comportamiento ELIMINANDO los DIV **container** y **todito** ?? Puedes venderme una plantilla que trabaje SIN esos 2 DIVs extra?. Te cuento que NO TIENE SCROL !!! :-) Excepto cuando las lineas se incrementan, éso es lo que he requerido. Cómo podria llamarse ESE diseño? Disculpa tantas molestias. :-) Felíz diciembre!

Answer (score 0):

Para responder la pregunta original:

`1// debo utilizar MÁS cajones "contenedores" para lograr el vertical al 100% ?`

con la **respuesta/solución** de @Elboy vemos que la opción es utilizar **FlexBox** al buscar ése tema, he llegado a https://www.udemy.com/course/curso-de-flexbox-desde-0/learn/lecture/5832324 (curso gratuito) y la respuesta es:

https://pasteboard.co/JB2Iep2.png

Por ahora la segunda pregunta continúa sin respuesta.